# Zooming UIImageView and moving inside the zoom

Tags: ios, uiimageview, zooming

in my UIScrollview i have a UIImageView with a black background. Inside of it there is another UIImageView with a UIImage inside and i use this code to enable the zoom:

```
fullImageView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,screenWidth,screenHeight)];
fullImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

[fullImageView addSubview:copyImageToShowImageView];

zoomFullImageScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,screenWidth,screenHeight)];

[zoomFullImageScrollView addSubview:fullImageView];

[self.view addSubview:zoomFullImageScrollView];

UIPinchGestureRecognizer *twoFingerTapRecognizer = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doubleTapImage:)];

[copyImageToShowImageView addGestureRecognizer:twoFingerTapRecognizer];


//Then..

- (void)doubleTapImage:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)gesture{

if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded
    || gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {

    CGFloat currentScale = copyImageToShowImageView.frame.size.width / copyImageToShowImageView.bounds.size.width;
    CGFloat newScale = currentScale * gesture.scale;

    NSLog(@"gesture.scale = %f", currentScale * gesture.scale);

    if (newScale < 1) {
        newScale = 1;
    }
    if (newScale > 100) {
        newScale = 100;
    }

    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(newScale, newScale);
    copyImageToShowImageView.transform = transform;
    gesture.scale = 1;

    copyImageToShowImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(copyImageToShowImageView.transform, newScale, newScale);
    zoomFullImageScrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(copyImageToShowImageView.frame.size.width, copyImageToShowImageView.frame.size.height);
}
}

//and the methods:

- (void)viewDidLoad {

NSLog(@"super");

[super viewDidLoad];

zoomFullImageScrollView.minimumZoomScale=0.5;
zoomFullImageScrollView.maximumZoomScale=6.0;
zoomFullImageScrollView.delegate=self;
}

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

    return copyImageToShowImageView;
}
```

This code works, but there is a problem because the scrollview content size is different from the UIImageView size. Maybe they're equal but not aligned. Then i'd like that when the user makes the zoom, the image zooms there, not always from the center, but this is not important..

I hope i explained myself.

How can i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put your UIImageView in a UIScrollView it will make your life easier.

The UIScrollView delegate implements methods specific to Zoom. And because it is scrollable you can "move" through the image.

In the UIScrollView's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/ZoomZoom/ZoomZoom.html) you can find good examples specifically related with zooming.

Comment: I update my answer because i had another problem using scrollview

Comment: Check [this](http://www.timoliver.com.au/2012/01/14/zooming-to-a-point-in-uiscrollview/) solution. This category enables the zooming to a specific point. I think you do not need to apply those  transformation that are applying.

Comment: Ok, i solved with UIScrollView and its delegate methods, thanks!